# Would "breaking point" only be used in a bad way?

Tags: idioms, usage

I wonder if there's any case where "breaking point" could be considered to be used as a disruptive-productive moment to express a deeply insightful moment.

Comment: Yes, you can break a vicious circle.

Comment: If you look at the [definition](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/used-to?q=used+to), it has negative connotations that are hard to make positive. You can turn "break" into a positive, i.e. "break down a wall" or "break a vicious cycle", but I don't know about "breaking point". It's usually used to warn of the imminent destruction of something that we would rather not see break. You might be thinking more of a turning/tipping point.

Comment: Thank you @ColleenV. Do you know what would be a best expression to emphasize that it's a destruction of something but it will bring good results in the end?

Comment: If that's what you're really looking for Tay, you should [edit] your question to include that - You might explain what kind of phrase you're looking for, and say "I thought of breaking point but I'm not sure if it is the right phrase."

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. When you "reach your breaking point", you have been pushed beyond your limit in some sense, and figuratively "snapped"

A good word for a moment of realisation is "epiphany".

Answer (score 1):

It would be difficult to put a positive slant on the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/breaking-point) definition of breaking point: **the stage at which your control over yourself or a situation is lost**.

A more appropriate term to use for a deeply insightful moment would be a [turning point](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turning-point) which is defined as **the time at which a situation starts to change in an important way**.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of positive outcome sure.

> Marco finally reach his breaking point and dumped his cheating boyfriend.

or

> The pinata is almost at it's breaking point, soon it will rain candy!

Answer (score 0):

The phrase

> breaking point

only has the meaning of *something* breaking if pushed beyond that point.

Without further context, it is not necessarily good nor bad, though often *something* breaking is not considered to be the best outcome.

However, with additional context, the *breaking point* can be a good thing

> [There are many things that can lead people to their ***breaking point*** when they come to the realization that they need to quit using drugs and alcohol for good.](http://talk.drugabuse.com/threads/breaking-point.5125/)
>
> [The pain associated to reaching the ***breaking point*** often makes people ingenious and creative...](https://books.google.com/books?id=HsRRkF-3z28C&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=pain+of+breaking+point+and+change&source=bl&ots=CaPtFlfOVw&sig=5Gdcm2HhBEeVFNjZRrRO6z2wXVQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYkPjQ4-zPAhWY0YMKHeVzC-4Q6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=pain%20of%20breaking%20point%20and%20change&f=false)

After passing the *breaking point* either *something* will be rendered broken and unusable, or may transform and change into *something* new and different.  It is this latter stage that primarily occupies peoples' ideas of whether a *breaking point* is good or bad.